# nodejs | getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined

Tags: node.js, express, dns

I'm stuck with the below error when trying to run a simple server with `express`.

```
Listening on port 3000
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)
```

Application versions

- node: 16.14.0
- mac: 12.2.1
- express: 4.17.1
- express-http-proxy: 1.6.0
- express-session: 1.17.0

`/etc/hosts` file

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

- I did a lot of research and came across this issue: https://eng.uber.com/denial-by-dns/
- tried with a lot of different `node` versions

It seems like a common problem for a lot of people.
I would appreciate any help to resolve this issue.